# Example of rejected alternative hypothesis of a Wilcoxon rank sum test?

Tags: r, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I've recently looked into the Wilcoxon Rank Sum test for comparing groups of continuous values. In particular I've been using R's `wilcox.test()` function for this task.

While using the test on my real data I noticed I wasn't getting any instances of the test rejecting the alternative hypothesis and all outputs always said `alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0`. I proceeded to do a quick test in R to see how a rejected alternative hypothesis result would look like:

```
>test1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
>test2 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
>test <- wilcox.test(test1, test2, alt="two.sided")
```

I was totally expecting a rejected alternative hypothesis here since both groups of values are equal but oh surprise:

```
> test

    Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  test1 and test2
W = 12.5, p-value = 1
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

By no means I'm experienced using Wilcoxon test, but I really can't see why the alternative hypothesis is accepted in this case. I know that the null hypothesis for this test expects the median of both groups to be equal, so I can't really tell why the example above didn't work as expected. Maybe this could be a matter of result interpretation in R? What would be a small example in which the alternative hypothesis would be rejected then?

Comment: `alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to zero` is just telling you what the alternative hypothesis is. It's not telling you the result of the test. For the test result, look to the reported *p* value.

Comment: does this mean that its entirely up to me deciding which hypothesis to take based on the p-value? if that is the case everything makes sense now lol

Comment: Yes, it's up to you to decide.  Usually it's framed as rejecting the null or failing to reject the null.

Comment: Excellent thank you for clearing that up, maybe you could post a short answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from comments: The text `alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to zero` is just telling you what the alternative hypothesis is. It's not telling you the result of the test. For the test result, look to the reported *p* value. Based on the *p* value and your selected alpha value, you either reject the null hypothesis or fail to reject the null hypothesis.